# Get .IPA-file for iPhone app

Tags: ios, itunes, ipa

Since iTunes now removed the possibility to download apps on iTunes - is there any way to get hold of an .ipa-file anymore?
I need to find out an url-scheme for an app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As iTunes 12.7 removed the support we can't do through iTunes.
I use the iMazing app to get the work done.
https://imazing.com/guides/how-to-manage-apps-without-itunes
Hope this helps you. 
One more suggestion is that, as you are using the .ipa to get the URL scheme, you can check the app’s official portal if they have any URL scheme defined to access their app. By this way, you can avoid the overhead of extracting the .ipa